# RecyclerView onBind, not binding the data

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am getting issue over here. On binding data, the public objects cannot be used. I was supposed to make a class which gets data from some other class and set text to some XML.

```
public class EventsAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{
private List<LauncherActivity.ListItem> listItems;
private Context context;
public EventsAdapter(List<LauncherActivity.ListItem> listItems, Context context) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_list, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    LauncherActivity.ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);
    holder.
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textHeading = null;
    public TextView textDescription = null;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textHeading = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewHead);
        textDescription = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewDesc);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Please add the code as text.

Comment: Surely its more difficult uploading the screenshots than copy pasting the code in a question.  Ever thought about people who may want to take your code and edit it so they can present an answer?

Comment: Let me edit the question please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using your ViewHolder that is why the methods can't be used

change this:

```
public class EventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

To this:

```
public class EventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> //your ViewHolder
```

Your onBindViewHolder it will be like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    LauncherActivity.ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its failing to resolve because you are using `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` in the onBind method. Use you custom `EventsAdapter.ViewHolder` class inorder to resolve your variables. For eg:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(EventsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

}
```

Comment: No, that don't gave solution.

Answer (score 0):

try change in extends for this..
    RecyclerView.Adapter<"EventsAdapter.ViewHolder"> without "" of course

Answer (score 0):

make your `EventsAdapter` extend `RecyclerView.Adapter<EventsAdapter.MyViewholder>` and then again implement methods and constructor, thus your `onBindViewHolder` will be created with `EventsAdapter.ViewHolder holder` itself.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this :

Make your EventsAdapter extend RecyclerView.Adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

   LauncherActivity.ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);
   holder.textHeading.setText(....)
}
```

or

with the help of typecasting

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

   LauncherActivity.ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);

     ((ViewHolder)holder).textHeading.setText(....)
}
```

And you are good to go. :) Happy Coding :)